# How to pass X_train + X_eval to Random Search CV fit method

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, xgboost

I'm trying to pass a set of [X_train, X_val] to X of `random_search.fit()` and the same to y with:
`random_search.fit(X=[X_train, X_val], y=[y_train, y_val])`

But when the training occurs the below error is displayed:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   TypeError: can not initialize DMatrix from list

[image]

I already tried using `group` field of fit method but I got another error. There any way of pass train/test and his evaluations sets for the fit method of Random Search? I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I have not understood correctly but if you want to use `RandomizedSearchCV` on 
the training and the validation samples concatenated together and use CV on this whole sample, 
I suggest using `np.concatenate` instead of list comprehension as follows:

```
# taking examples for your X_train, X_val, y_train and y_val
import numpy as np
X_train = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
X_val = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
y_train = np.array([10, 11, 12])
y_val = np.array([13, 14])

data = np.concatenate((X_train, X_val), axis=0)
target = np.concatenate((y_train, y_val))
```

And you can pass `data` and `target` to the fit method.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I taught I had to pass them together as a list or similar. Thank you!